# CSS border bigger than picture

Tags: php, css, image, border

I'm trying to find out how I can make the border around my picture bigger than the image it self in CSS. See the pictures for an example:

Wrong border:

[image: Black circle with a black box around it. The box is just big enough for the circle to fit.]

Correct border:

[image: Black circle with a black box around it. The box is larger than the one in the previous image so there is white space between the circle and the box around it.]

I want the image to be the original size independent from the border "size".

Comment: don't even really need a span. you can style the image's borders directly... and those would automatically/naturally be the same size as the image.

Comment: Marc makes a good point. Please clarify if you just need a border or a border with some padding.  The example image looks like white padding with a black border, but it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e74Lq4gr/1/)

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.langology.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/hello1.jpg"/>
```

CSS:

```
img{
border-color: black;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
padding: 5px;
```

}

You can vary the padding value so that you can adjust the border with respect to image.

Comment: I like this answer. I had to support IE6 for so many years that I didn't even think to add padding directly to an image (which doesn't work in IE quirks mode). D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

You need padding on the image's parent element to push the border out away from the image.

Comment: Yes, but don't think of it as pushing a border, but rather adding space between a container and it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image in a `<div>` and set specific height and width values for that div. Then add the border to the div instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css padding on the image element or it's parent to achieve your desired effect. See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) for more information.